# MOSFET Relay (G3VM-21AR/DR) connected to Arduino Digital Pin

Tags: arduino, mosfet, relay, solid-state-relay

I am trying to figure out how to go about using this Omron MOSFET relay in my project. I will be sending 12V (car voltage) to a radar detector and I want to be able to turn it on/off whenever via the Digital Pin on an Arduino board (max 5V output).

When the digital pin is high it allows 12V to flow to the radar. When the digital pin is low then it shuts out the 12V so no power is going to the radar.

[image]

[PDF](http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g3vm_21ar_dr.pdf)

Do I have the schematic above correct? Am I leaving something out?

**Update**

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a resistor in series with the LED, which is inside of the solid state relay (SSR).

More importantly, however, the sketch in the O.P. is a bit <strike>backwards</strike> sideways.  Control signal is between pins 1 & 2.  High current path is between pins 3 & 4.

[image]

Comment: Would this same setup be suitable with an rca video input (yellow plug) in place of the 12vdc? Would it mess with the signal any when going through it?

Comment: @StealthRT  The SSR might limit the bandwidth of the signal.  But, I don't know enough about video signal to say for sure.

Comment: For this one http://www.clare.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/D4D22906656FCF5C8525749B004957B8/$file/LCA717.pdf i am looking at the **DC Load only** and am confused... The **+ Load** is on pins 4 and 6 while the **- Load** is on pin 5. Can you explain to me how i would hook that up using my current 12vdc connection (12v in / 12v out)??

Comment: see my post about that question above: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86318/lca717-ssr-connected-to-arduino-digital-pin

Comment: Does it matter what pin (4 or 3) i use as the "input" and "output"? In your drawing you have pin 3 as output and pin 4 as input. In my drawing i have Pin 3 as input while pin 4 is output.... Which is correct?

Comment: @StealthRT  With this model, it doesn't matter.  It's symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

Pins 1 and 2 are the LED (the "coil" of the relay) and 3 and 4 are the output side (the "contacts").

Pin 1 should go to the Arduino's +5V via a resistor - 390 or 430 ohms would be a suitable value.  Pin 2 will go to the Aduino output terminal.

+12 Volts should go to pin 3, and pin 4 to your load.